# How to calculate a value using checkbox AngularJs in a repeater

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I use a ngRepeat with a checkbox and need when I check each item compute the value total of selected items as below:

HTML:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="ciclo in ciclos">
   <td><input id="idCiclo" type="checkbox" ng-click="computeTotal(ciclo)">
   </td>
   <td>{{ciclo.Quantity}}</td>
   <td>{{ciclo.Value | currency}}</td>
    ...
<tfoot>
 <tr>
  ...
  <td>{{TotalQuantity}}</td>...
```

Controller:

```
 $scope.computeTotal = function (ciclo) {
   $scope.TotalQuantity += ciclo.Quantity; //Here I need Add or Subtract a value 
 };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a property that indicates whether a checkbox has been checked or unchecked so that you can decide to add or subtract.

You would be using `ngModel` with `ngChange` (`ngClick` is usually better for elements that don't have built-in click expectations/behaviors).

Example:

View:

```
<tr ng-repeat="ciclo in ciclos">
   <td>
        <input class="ciclo" type="checkbox" ng-model="ciclo.checked" ng-change="computeTotal(ciclo)">
   <!-- Note that I took out the ID. IDs should never be used in ngRepeat,
        as it heavily risks multiple elements having the same ID,
        which should ALWAYS be unique.
        A class works much better for collections like this. -->
   </td>
   <td>{{ciclo.Quantity}}</td>
   <td>{{ciclo.Value | currency}}</td>
</tr>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.computeTotal = function (ciclo) {
    if(ciclo.checked)
        $scope.TotalQuantity += ciclo.Quantity;
    else
        $scope.TotalQuantity -= ciclo.Quantity;
};
```